# Is there a way in Java to find out what String a Scanner skipped over?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The Scanner class provides a convenient method to skip over whitespace and get complete string tokens. However, I am encountering the following situation-

I have input as follows-

```
   Public Type XYZ
       A(3) As Byte
       B(0) As Byte
       C(0) As Byte
   End Type
```

I am using a Scanner to scan through input like this. The scanner correctly returns tokens like "Public", "Type", "XYZ", etc. However, is there a way to find out what was skipped? For instance, after XYZ, the scanner actually skips a "\n" instead of a blankspace - " ". How to find out what the scanner skipped over?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible as it treats all white space alike, as far as I know. Perhaps you need to use a more robust parser of some sort to do this. ?Yacc perhaps? I don't know since this is way out of my comfort zone.

Comment: `\n` *is* whitespace. There's no "instead" involved here :)

Comment: That being said ... if that's not what you want, you can change the delimiter with the `useDelimiter()` method and only have it skip over spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible as the Scanner class returns the tokens without the trailing delimiter. In this case, without the trailing whitespace character. I don't believe there is a way to get it back.

One solution would be to parse the file line by line using the [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) classes. That way you have full access to the characters individually.

Comment: Hmmm. I wish they had that functionality in the Scanner class.